# how to autocomplete options in vim command mode

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

my setting for command mode completion is:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest,list,full
```

currently when i type

```
:set fdm=
```

in command mode, then press tab, manual appended, if i Press tab again , character ^I appended, what i want is manual changed to another foldmethod options such as syntax, indent and so on.

does anyone know is that possible or if there is any plugin could do that ?

thanks !

Answer (score 2):

As you say, when you press `<Tab>` after `:set fdm=`, you get `manual`inserted.

That could seem the usual autocomplete behaviour we are used to in many places, `manual` being just the first of all possible values. So, you expect that repeating `<Tab>` will give you more possibilites.

But that's not indeed the case. What you get when pressing `<Tab>` in such a situation is **not the first autocompletion alternative, but the current option value**. So, you're getting `manual` because that's in fact the default value for that option. Successive `<Tab>`s get inserted literally, as this behaviour is only fired right after `=`.

From Vim's help:

```
The old value of an option can be obtained by hitting 'wildchar' just after
the '='.  For example, typing 'wildchar' after ":set dir=" will insert the
current value of 'dir'.  This overrules file name completion for the options
that take a file name.
```

So, what you described is expected behaviour. See `:help cmdline-completion` for the whole story.

I don't know about any plugin capable of changing this to what you want.